# Trilateration Formula (Programming)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, trilateration

I'm currently trying to develop a trilateration application to track beacons using 3 phones. I converted code I found in python over to c# but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
This is my code:

```
public double[] getPosition(double phoneADistance, double phoneBDistance, double phoneCDistance)
    {
        //meterToFeet is just a conversion method which takes the distance parameter and multiplies it by 3.28.
        double PhoneADist = meterToFeet(phoneADistance);
        double PhoneBDist = meterToFeet(phoneBDistance);
        double PhoneCDist = meterToFeet(phoneCDistance);

        //The phone's x and y coordinates are pre-set
        Vector<double> P1 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneA_x, PhoneA_y });
        Vector<double> P2 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneB_x, PhoneB_y });
        Vector<double> P3 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneC_x, PhoneC_y });

        var ex = (P2 - P1) / (P2 - P1).L2Norm();
        var i = ex.DotProduct(P3 - P1);
        var ey = (P3 - P1 - i * ex) / (P3 - P1 - i * ex).L2Norm();
        var d = (P2 - P1).L2Norm();
        var j = ey.DotProduct(P3 - P1);

        var x = (Math.Pow(PhoneADist, 2) - Math.Pow(PhoneBDist, 2) + Math.Pow(d, 2)) / (2 * d);
        var y = ((Math.Pow(PhoneADist, 2) - Math.Pow(PhoneCDist, 2) + Math.Pow(i, 2) + Math.Pow(j, 2)) / (2 * j)) - ((i / j) * x);


        double[] answer = new double[] { x, y };
        Console.Write(x + " " + y);
        return answer;
    }
```

When I run this method

*Test case #1:*

- PhoneA_x&y = (0,0)
- PhoneB_x&y = (100,0)
- PhoneC_x&y = (50,100)
- phoneADistance = 0
- phoneBDistance = 100
- phoneCDistance = 111.803

it returns (-488.195, -366.147)

*Test Case #2:*

- PhoneA_x&y = (0,0)
- PhoneB_x&y = (100,0)
- PhoneC_x&y = (50,100)
- phoneADistance = 25
- phoneBDistance = 25
- phoneCDistance = 25

it returns (50, 37.5)

Comment: How does the result differ from what's expected?  When you step through in a debugger, at what point does the calculation differ from what's expected?

Comment: @David In test case #1, the answer should be positive and be at position (0,0).
Also, in most of my test cases, they almost always returns (50,37.5) which is wrong.

Comment: Where did the test data come from? It doesn't look like these numbers could solve the equations if correct.

Comment: @Simon They were just dummy test data that I plugged in to test the algorithm

Comment: Oh and it's using the MathNet Numerics library to calculate the dot products and norms as well as for the vector structures.

Comment: The reason I ask is that the algorithm is supposed to be the intersection of 3 circles centred at x,y with radius as your distance number. (See the picture in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration). Using the numbers you're testing with the circles wouldn't overlap, so no wonder the results are unexpected.

Comment: Could you try the numbers from this page http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa05/Schultz/6690/Barn_GPS/Barn_GPS.html

Comment: A: r = 13 x,y: (0, 0), B: r = 5 x,y: (9, 15), C: r = 20 x,y: (21, 0), output: (5, 12)

Comment: @Simon Just tried plugging it in, but I'm getting output: (53.027, -88.576)

Comment: Could you try it without converting the distances to feet first, that is probably messing up the calculation.

Comment: @Simon I think there was something wrong with the algorithm to start off with. Instead of that algorithm, I tried redoing the whole algorithm based off the link you attached. I will be back with updates tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very sloppy but this is my new algorithm so far.

I just took the excel spreadsheet from the site that Simon linked and converted into C# code.

There is still a lot of clean up to do.

*It's still in testing process so I'm not 100 with the results, but from the testings I've done so far it seems pretty accurate.*

```
    public double[] getPosition(double phoneADistance, double phoneBDistance, double phoneCDistance)
    {
        double[] answer = new double[] { 0, 0 };
        double PhoneADist = meterToFeet(phoneADistance);
        double PhoneBDist = meterToFeet(phoneBDistance);
        double PhoneCDist = meterToFeet(phoneCDistance);

        Vector<double> P1 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneA_x, PhoneA_y });
        Vector<double> P2 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneB_x, PhoneB_y });
        Vector<double> P3 = new DenseVector(new[] { PhoneC_x, PhoneC_y });

        //Translate values for the three points
        var B3 = PhoneA_x;
        var C3 = PhoneA_y;
        var D3 = phoneADistance;
        var B4 = PhoneB_x;
        var C4 = PhoneB_y;
        var D4 = phoneBDistance;
        var B5 = PhoneC_x;
        var C5 = PhoneC_y;
        var D5 = phoneCDistance;
        //Translate P1 to Origin
        var B8 = B3 - B3;
        var C8 = C3 - C3;
        var D8 = D3;
        var B9 = B4 - B3;
        var C9 = C4 - C3;
        var D9 = D4;
        var B10 = B5 - B3;
        var C10 = C5 - C3;
        var D10 = D5;
        //Find Calculation Values
        var B13 = Math.Atan2(C9, B9); ;
        var B14 = Math.Atan2(C10, B10);
        var B15 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B4 - B3, 2) + Math.Pow(C4 - C3, 2));
        var B16 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B5 - B3, 2) + Math.Pow(C5 - C3, 2));
        //Polar Coordinates for the Rotated System
        //var B20 = 0;
        //var C20 = 0;
        var D20 = D3;
        var B21 = B15;
        //var C21 = 0;
        var D21 = D4;
        var B22 = B16;
        var C22 = B14 - B13;
        var D22 = D5;
        //Rectangular Coordinates for the Rotated System
        //var B26 = 0;
        //var C26 = 0;
        var D26 = D3;
        var B27 = B21;
        //var C27 = 0;
        var D27 = D4;
        var B28 = B22 * Math.Cos(C22);
        var C28 = B22 * Math.Sin(C22);
        var D28 = D5;
        //Coordinates of Roated Solution
        var B31 = (Math.Pow(D3, 2) - Math.Pow(D4, 2) + Math.Pow(B27, 2)) / (B27 * 2);
        var B32 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(D3, 2) - Math.Pow(B31, 2));
        var D32 = -B32;
        //Convert to Polar
        var B35 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(B31, 2) + Math.Pow(B32, 2));
        var B36 = Math.Atan2(B32, B31);
        var D36 = Math.Atan2(D32, B31);
        //Unrotate
        var B39 = B35;
        var B40 = B36 + B13;
        var D40 = D36 + B13;
        //Rectangular Coordinates
        var B43 = B39 * Math.Cos(B40);
        var D43 = B39 * Math.Cos(D40);
        var B44 = B39 * Math.Sin(B40);
        var D44 = B39 * Math.Sin(D40);
        //Untranslate
        var B47 = B43 + B3;
        var D47 = D43 + B3;
        var B48 = B44 + C3;
        var D48 = D44 + C3;
        var x = B47;
        var y = B48;
        //Return Answer
        if (!Double.IsNaN(x) || !Double.IsNaN(y))
        {
            answer = new double[] { x, y };
            Console.Write(x + " " + y);
        }
        return answer;
    }
```